# Change a function parameter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, code-cleanup

I use an HTML button to call a function :

```
<button id="attackButton" type="button" onclick="Enemy.prototype.fight(Test)">  Attaquer    </button>
```

This function is :

```
Enemy.prototype.fight = function(Enemy) 
{
}
```

This function is linked to these 2 variables :

```
var Enemy = function (damage, life) 
{
    this.damage = damage;
    this.life= life;
};

var Test= new Enemy (7,20);
```

I would like to make something which will replace the parameter"Test" by "Test2" within the HTML Button so my button will now redirect to the same function while using a third variable :

```
var Test2= new Enemy (10,30);
```

I hope I was clear enough. Thank you. :)

EDIT :

To clarify : A player is fighting different enemies. Enemies have different variables (armor, life, damage etc...) The fight is a function and variables varies based on the parameter. The html button calls that function.

The player is going to make various actions within the game and sometimes he will fight. Sometimes he will not.

I would like to keep one single html button which always call the same function. But the parameter has to change each time I want it.

For instance :

If you take the left side, then you fight Enemy 1.
If you take the right side, then you fight Enemy 2.

Right now the full the full Enemy function is

```
var Enemy = function (damage, initiative, armor, lifeNow, life) 
{
    this.damage = damage;
    this.initiative = initiative;
    this.armor = armor;
    this.lifeNow = lifeNow;
    this.life = life;
};
```

and each time I want to add a different enemy I write this :

```
var enemy1= new Enemy (7, 9, 3, 15, 15);
var enemy2= new Enemy (50, 9, 3, 100, 100);
```

Hope it helps :p Thank you again

Comment: You should probably refactor the code so that you aren't hardcoding `Test` into the onclick function  in the first place.

Comment: Also you should not call prototype methods like this. `Test2.fight(Test)` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the variable from the button click event into a kind of context like the game in my example and in this way you can change the enemies any time you want.

For example if the side is changed just call: changeEnemy(game1, enemy2);

```js
    var Enemy = function (damage, initiative, armor, lifeNow, life) 
    {
        this.damage = damage;
        this.initiative = initiative;
        this.armor = armor;
        this.lifeNow = lifeNow;
        this.life = life;
    };

    Enemy.prototype.fight = function(enemy) {
        alert('it works!' + enemy.damage);
    }

    var Game = function (enemy1, enemy2)
    {
        this.enemy1 = enemy1;
        this.enemy2= enemy2;
      
        this.fight = function () {
            this.enemy1.fight(this.enemy2); 
        }
    };

    var enemy1= new Enemy (7, 9, 3, 15, 15);
    var enemy2= new Enemy (50, 9, 3, 100, 100);
    var enemy3= new Enemy (60, 9, 3, 100, 100);
    var game1= new Game(enemy1, enemy2);

    function changeEnemy(game, newEnemy) {
      game.enemy2 = newEnemy;
    }

    changeEnemy(game1, enemy3);
```

```html
<button id="attackButton" type="button" onclick="game1.fight();">  Attaquer    </button>
```

Comment: 1. Variable `Game` does not have `fight` method. 2. `this.enemy...` assignments only make sense if `new Game(...)` is called.

Comment: you are right sire, this is not the whole code just a prototype of an idea supposing that who wants to you use it is able to use it ;)
(but if it bothers you it can be extended)

Comment: The enemies are supposed to be fought by (presumably) the user, not each other. I don't see how this changes who gets fought each time the button is clicked either. This is a problem since that was the point of the question.

Comment: he asked this: Enemy.prototype.fight(Test) with this: var Test2= new Enemy (10,30); I guess it means Enemy object against enemy object. I wrote one line at the end of the comment saying that the enemies can be changed any time because he did not mention when he wants to change them

Comment: @Quentin, could you please explain why this is not an answer for the old and the edited question?

Comment: @harcos — Your code causes two enemies to fight each other. It does not cause the player to fight a different enemy depending on some condition.

Comment: @Quentin, my code uses the same fight method what Boby has used, right? then could you please point out the difference?

Comment: Hmm. You're right. It doesn't cause two enemies to fight each other. It just uses the fight method on enemy1 to cause the player to fight enemy2, which is bizarre. It also causes the player to *always* fight enemy2, so still doesn't conditionally change which enemy the player is fighting.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm still wrong. `fight` is never exposed as a property on the Game instance, so what it actually does is throw an `undefined is not a function` error.

Comment: @Quentin: you are right with the property I made mistake this is right, but I still don't get the earlier blame, Enemy.prototype.fight is not the same as new Enemy(...).fight ???

Comment: See my previous but one comment.

Comment: @Quentin, so you say it is not the same, right?
(and your question about how to change enemy2 I wrote earlier because Boby never said in the question that enemy should be changed for the click on the attack button, enemy can be changed for any event of the game)

Comment: Your code doesn't show how to change the enemy being attacked at all.

Comment: OK, I got it you just wanted to downvote because you don't understand. I showed a concept how he can manage the problem and I wrote that he only needs to change the property of the game instance so everything was written but I didn't develop code instead of him I just helped but now I changed my post and sent a working code because I can see now that lazy people don't want to think

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to make a couple of assumptions here. The main one is that you have a number of Enemy objects and you want to attack each one in sequence.

First, **use an array, not sequentially named variables**.

```
var enemies = [ new Enemy (7,20), new Enemy (10,30) ];
```

Second, track which enemy is next to be attacked:

```
var nextEnemy = 0;
```

Third, refactor your code to make the attack enemy logic a function of its own.

Attack the current next enemy and then work out which one should be attacked after that.

```
function attackNextEnemy() {
    Enemy.prototype.fight(enemies[nextEnemy]);
    nextEnemy++;
    if (!enemies[nextEnemy]) {
        nextEnemy = 0; // back to the top
    }
}
```

You can then call that function from onclick.

There are various other things you could to that would be better practises (such as mentioned in dfsq's comment, using `addEventListener` instead of HTML attributes), and putting the nextEnemy variable inside a closure to keep it private, but a Stackoverflow answer isn't the place to go into that level of depth.

---

After the question was updated:

> If you take the left side, then you fight Enemy 1. If you take the right side, then you fight Enemy 2.

In that case, you probably don't want to use an array. You are dealing with positions not sequences.

An object such as:

```
var enemies = { 
    left: new Enemy (7,20), 
    right: new Enemy (10,30)
};
```

… would make more sense.

Then you would need to change your attack to:

```
var sideThePlayerIsOn = "left";
```

and

```
Enemy.prototype.fight(enemies[sideThePlayerIsOn]);
```

as well as adding some logic to change the `sideThePlayerIsOn` variable based on whatever the player can do to change that.

Comment: `Enemy.prototype.fight(...)`?

Comment: @Igor — is what the code in the original question uses. Converting it to something sane is outside the scope of the actual problem. See also the last paragraph of the answer and dfsq's comment on the question.

Comment: Hello, I think it is what I am looking for or near. You supposed well. The player which never changes fight different enemies. Each enemies have different variables. Using an array would be great of course but I am not sure how to write it.                  I am going to edit my first message

Comment: @Boby — I've extended the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am a beginner and I am amazed by the help I already received here. Unfortunately I dont get everything within your code. I will take time to think about. I also think I finally found my own way to do this. But it also leads to other questions... ^^